# Change Boot Animation 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, dell, xps, animations

How to implement [Dell XPS 13's boot animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apx_HyxFqjA) to our Ubuntu 16.04 LTS System?

Thanks!

Comment: This is talking about the **first boot**, and it's over 4 years old.

Comment: I know it is old but, for example Windows 10 Shows a Logo and dots, My ubuntu show nothing except dark screens and console logs.

Comment: Looks very interesting but I'm not sure if it's possible to use a video as a boot animation